# How to return a new key onchange location in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, rootscope

The idea is to always have a new key as soon as you change the page, this is my code but I think I have problem

```
$scope.newKey =function (){
    var key =0;
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
      key++ ;

    });
    return key;
};
```

If one of you has already tried `$locationChangeSuccess` it can help me thank you

Comment: Why do you need to user a function? Perhaps, that way will be better: `$scope.newKey = 0; $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () { $scope.newKey++; });`

Comment: always $scope.newKey = 0

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using angular's **service or factory**, so that it includes the Scope variable **key** which is actually globally available to the entire app/module?  i mean this is just my view though

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure - how exactly you want to use your "newKey", but if you need it on your html, then the valverde93's answer is correct:
`$scope.newKey = 0;` 
`$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () { $scope.newKey++; });`
And on your html:
`{{newKey}}`
But if you want to use it on your backend (the js files like a function) - then you get always $scope.newKey = 0, just because you're put your console.log after the incrementation function, and you see only the $scope.newKey = 0;
So if you put your console.log in the function - something like:
`$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () { $scope.newKey++; console.log($scope.newKey);});`
then you'll see your proper key.

 Or you may to use $watch, to check when the scope is changed and to do somthing: 
`$scope.$watch('newKey', function(newValue ) {
            console.log( newValue );
          }
      );`
Good luck.